# Blank page when using post method to send data from a jsp login form to a servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

i'm following this tutorial right [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-login-form-in-servlet) 
Copied and past exact code, changed servlet's name and the mapping in web.xml as well, but when i try to login (as "admin", exists in mysql database), i get a blank page with the following url :
`http://localhost:8080/project6/LoginServdo?username=admin&password=admin`
And nothing happens, if anyone encoutred this problem before, thank you in advance.

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: Quickly scanning the code, it may be that your WelcomeServlet needs to accept requests via doGet rather than doPost. One standard trick is to have doPost call doGet with the same parameters. I suggest you use some standard debugging methods to try to track down precisely where the failure is occuring.

Comment: Stacktrace?? Probably Exception

Answer (score 1):

If you fall off the end of a `doGet()` or `doPost()` without sending anything back to the browser, you're going to get a blank page.

After a `doPost()`, it's common to send a redirect, doing something like

```
response.sendRedirect("/loggedin");
```

where the `/loggedin` handler emits HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If your URL looks like that, then your form method probably isn't **post**. So check that out, it should be:

```
<form action="servlet1" method="post">
```

Or you can just add this to your `WelcomeServlet`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
```